# ASP.NET fails to send email through Gmail SMTP, but Outlook 2007 succeeds

Tags: asp.net, outlook, smtp, gmail

Hi all
a couple weeks ago, my ASP.NET website stopped sending user comments which I implemented by emailing those comments to my email account through Gmail SMTP server (smtp.gmail.com). I opened the project on my development machine and again it fails to send the email after a couple minutes with the following exception message:

> Failure sending mail
>
> Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.

I'm using Gmail's SMTP with port 465, and MailClient.EnableSSL = True.
The weird thing is my Office Outlook 2007 is using the same settings and it doesn't have any problems sending mail using the same Gmail account.

Any thoughts?

Comment: To clarify, it was working in your production env. but is now not working in either prod or locally?

Comment: It was working just fine everywhere. 2 weeks ago we realized the site is problematic; when we checked we realized that it no longer works, neither on the production server nor locally. Then I used my Office Outlook 2007 to see if there is a problem in my local connection or gmail isacting up, and it sends mail just fine (using the same mail account we use in the web site).

Answer (score 4):

This code works for me.  Note the port number is different to the 465 you are trying.  I'm almost certain I also tried 465 first with no luck.

```
var msg = new MailMessage(new MailAddress(recipient, "SCS Web Site"), new MailAddress(toAddress))
                {
                    Body = BuildMailBody(),
                    Subject = "SCS Web Site Message"
                };
var smtp = new SmtpClient
                {
                    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                    Port = 587,
                    EnableSsl = true,
                    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(myGmailUser, myGmailPassword)
                };
smtp.Send(msg);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but those settings don't work. Using port# 587 I get the message "Failure sending mail-Unable to connect to the remote server". Even if your port# worked, that wouldn't explain why my Office Outlook can send mail using 465. This is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't happen to have a firewall disallowing outbound connections here then, say, specifically allowed outlook to punch through . . .

Comment: I realized the problem when our main server failed to send mail (2 weeks ago). Then I tested the code on my development machine and the same thing happened. No one touched either machine; so I don't think it has anything to do with the firewall.

Answer (score -1):

One oddity I found with formmail going through gmail (on Windows server) was that the port number was the problem. My code was similar to yours, but it only worked when I changed the port to 25 rather than the 587 or 465. That might be what you need here.