# ASP.net MVC Sending Mail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, smtp

This is my code to send mail (test code):

```
//sending mail
var message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress("J2v@gmail.com");
message.To.Add(model.Mailag);
message.Subject = "Valdation d'inscription";
message.Body = "Votre inscription a été valide voici vos cordonne de conexion ID user : "+model.Idag+" Password : "+user.password;
var client = new  System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
{
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("", "")
};
client.Send(message);
```

When I try it I got this error:

> SMTP server require secured connexion or you are not connected. Server response was :5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at

on this line: `client.Send(message);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET fails to send email through Gmail SMTP, but Outlook 2007 succeeds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420875/asp-net-fails-to-send-email-through-gmail-smtp-but-outlook-2007-succeeds)

Comment: Doesn't work, i saw your link and always same result. and check my post i have update it.

Comment: Have you tried with the `Port`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following settings when relying to GMAIL:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
var credentials = System.Net.NetworkCredential(”yourid@gmail.com”, “yourpwd”);
smtp.Credentials = credentials;
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Port = 587;
```

Comment: @Chlebta, you have failed to include the flag to not use default credentials as Giorgio recommended in his code.

Comment: I used default credentials i have updated my code just chech it.

Comment: @Chlebta you DO NOT need to use the default credentials, use smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

Comment: UseDefaultCredentials = false; it already used in my code check my post please i have update it.

Comment: it work now just i used only my gmail id not the hole mail adresse `myid@gmail.com`
`var credentials = System.Net.NetworkCredential(”yourid”, “yourpwd”);`

Comment: Can I send Email even I don't authenticate the user?

Answer (score 1):

I expect you will need to pass in your username, password and a port number when using `smtp.gmail.com`

Try using

```
var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
client.Port = 587;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("accountID", "accountPassword");
client.EnableSsl = true;

client.Send(message);
```

Answer (score 1):

when "SMTP server require secured connectionor you are not connected. Server response was :5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at on this line client.Send(message)" occurs while sending mail means,

you have 2-step verification in your gmail account... remove it and run your code.. it works