# (MVC) Sending Email with user Credential

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, model-view-controller, sendmail, credentials

I searched a lot about sending emails using **MVC** but all of the result is talking about **static** user Credentials, I want to get those Credentials from the user name by making him login his *email provider* and get the credentials from this process. 
thanks for help!!.

Comment: Hi, Really unsure what you mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044887/asp-net-mvc-sending-mail       this link for post about how to send email using mvc

Comment: but the problem is that I must specify the email and the password for the sender .

Comment: hi, I am going to mark this 'Unclear what you asking' - Please read this before posting https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - Thanks

Comment: What I want is to get those Credentials ( email and password) from the user email provider

Comment: Hi please elaborate your problem more.Are you looking forward to create email client ? which user can login & send email? Just like we do in gmail or hotmail?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are making a smtp client application using MVC model in ASP.NET and you need how to authenticate some portal-site or how to use window credentials. Right? If yes, you should study [OAUTH2](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/authenticate-oauth-aspnet-core-2) or [Window Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio).